# SBT can not resolve sbt-echo-play

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-stack, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to deploy my play app in production mode. There is unresolved dependency error.

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-echo-play;0.1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-echo-play;0.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/d.mikhaylov/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-echo-play/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   file:/var/home/d.mikhaylov/server/repository/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-echo-play/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-echo-play_2.10_0.13/0.1.1/sbt-echo-play-0.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-echo-play_2.10_0.13/0.1.1/sbt-echo-play-0.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-echo-play/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Artifactory: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/repo/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-echo-play_2.10_0.13/0.1.1/sbt-echo-play-0.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-echo-play_2.10_0.13/0.1.1/sbt-echo-play-0.1.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-echo-play;0.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-echo-play:0.1.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases",
  Resolver.url("scala sbt",  url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  Resolver.url("typesafe ivy",  url("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)
```

Comment: Thank it works now. Could you please explain why it did not with typesafe resolver only? And why default activator template doesn't have this two URLs?